# Emails sent using SMTP Gmail don't get delivered

Tags: laravel, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send mails from my webserver using Laravel 6 like this:

```
Mail::send('feedback', ['email' => $email, 'text' => $text], function($message) use ($receiver)
        {
            $message->to($receiver, 'The receiver')->subject('New Feedback');
        });
```

I added my login information into my .env file according to this page from google:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=de

my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=xxxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=my_gmail_login_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

but my mails don't get sent/delivered. I don't get any error message or anything logged. Everything seems to be working, but for some reason they don't get delivered.

I tried it with enabling insecure apps in my gmail settings and using my gmail password and also with creating an app password and using the app password. Both options didn't work.

Does someone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Change your `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail` to `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `.env` variables as below:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

or

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: As PK Tharindu suggested. The SSL works on port 465

Answer (score 0):

You should set the .env attribute as below

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=username
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

Give it a try.